# Read data from form which is not mapped with entity

Tags: symfony

I created form in controller. Form is not related with entity.

```
 public function formularzAction(Request $request) 
    $form = $this->createFormBuilder()
            ->add('task', TextType::class, array('mapped' => false))
            ->add('dueDate', DateType::class, array('mapped' => false))
            ->add('save', SubmitType::class, array('label' => 'Create Post'))
            ->getForm();
    $form->handleRequest($request);
    if ($form->isSubmitted()) {
        $t = $form->getData();
        return new Response(form['task']->getData());
    }
    return $this->render('JakubBundle:Default:formularz.html.twig', array(
                'form' => $form->createView()
    ));
}
```

I am trying to read form data.
$form['task']->getData() is working but $form['dueDate']->getData() not. Error message is "The Response content must be a string or object implementing __toString(), "object" given. "
How should I solve problem. Thanks for help in advance.

Comment: `return new Response(form['task']->getData());` should be `return new Response($form['task']->getData());` probably....

Comment: dump($t); all the data you need should be in there as a simple array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$form['dueDate']->getData()` returns a DateTime object.

http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php

You should get a string representation of that object.

One possibility is to call a `format()` method on the DateTime object.

For example:

```
$dt = $form['task']->getData();
return new Response($dt->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')));
```

http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php